# Is there any way to convert an Oracle resultSet to XML?

Tags: java, xml, oracle, resultset

I want to convert an Oracle resultSet, which fetched data from a table/set of tables and put it inside an XML tag. (One tag for each column of the resultSet)

How can I do this in Java?

Comment: Is Oracle XSQL still a thing?

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e23094/xdb13gen.htm#ADXDB4987

Answer (score -1):

First of all there is no oracle resultset (at least, I never heard). If you have stored data in a result set, you simply can use it as you want (copy to array, make a file or anything). If you don't know how to create an xml file I think [this](https://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-create-xml-file-in-java-dom/) could help

https://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-create-xml-file-in-java-dom/